# Cannot send emails to foreign domains

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I try to send emails through ASP.NET interface and can't get it to work. Emails are sent, but only if the receiver of the email has the same domain name as my server (receiver@mydomain.com). The weird thing is, I actually CAN send such emails from any email program. So it seems that my Web.config file is missing something (?), although it looks ok (for me):

```
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="mydomain.com" userName="info@mydomain.com" password="XXX" port="25" defaultCredentials="false" />    
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, I'm using local SMTP server

Comment: do you receive any error message?

Comment: Have you checked the logs of your SMTP server?  It seems much more likely the problem is there, not in your application.

Comment: no errors and logs seem OK for me

Comment: Just to confirm, when you use other email programs, are they all set up through your local SMTP server? Or is it only the ASP.NET application using the local SMTP server?

Comment: They all using the same (local) SMTP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it was a provider issue